# HTML tabs with javascript do not work with shiny runtime in rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have no problem with the following html tabs and java script in a normal rmarkdown.  However, I have encounter a difficulty after adding `runtime: shiny` in yaml.  The contents are not displayed.

````html
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "John Doe"
date: "2022-11-28"
output: html_document
#runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```





<!-- Tab links -->

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="tablabel(event, 'app_1')">Application 1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="tablabel(event, 'app_2')">Application 2</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="app_1" class="tabcontent" style="display:block">
This is the content for application 1.
</div>


<div id="app_2" class="tabcontent">
This is the content for application 2.
</div>


<style type = "text/css">
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  /*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
  /*background-color: #f1f1f1;*/
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
  background-color: #f1e4ff;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-left:0.3em;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #e4e5ff;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ffe4ff;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  /*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
  border-top: none;
}
</style>


<script>
function tablabel(evt, tabName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
````

```html
My session info is:


R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tibble_3.1.8        dplyr_1.0.10        ggplot2_3.4.0       Spectra_1.8.0      
[5] ProtGenerics_1.29.1 BiocParallel_1.30.3 S4Vectors_0.34.0    BiocGenerics_0.42.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9        assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.30     utf8_1.2.2       
 [5] mime_0.12         R6_2.5.1          evaluate_0.18     pillar_1.8.1     
 [9] rlang_1.0.6       curl_4.3.3        rstudioapi_0.14   jquerylib_0.1.4  
[13] rmarkdown_2.18    labeling_0.4.2    stringr_1.4.1     munsell_0.5.0    
[17] shiny_1.7.3       compiler_4.2.0    httpuv_1.6.6      xfun_0.35        
[21] pkgconfig_2.0.3   askpass_1.1       htmltools_0.5.3   openssl_2.0.4    
[25] tidyselect_1.2.0  IRanges_2.30.0    codetools_0.2-18  fansi_1.0.3      
[29] withr_2.5.0       later_1.3.0       MASS_7.3-56       grid_4.2.0       
[33] jsonlite_1.8.3    xtable_1.8-4      gtable_0.3.1      lifecycle_1.0.3  
[37] DBI_1.1.3         magrittr_2.0.3    MsCoreUtils_1.8.0 scales_1.2.1     
[41] cli_3.4.1         stringi_1.7.8     cachem_1.0.6      farver_2.1.1     
[45] fs_1.5.2          promises_1.2.0.1  bslib_0.4.1       ellipsis_0.3.2   
[49] generics_0.1.3    vctrs_0.5.1       tools_4.2.0       glue_1.6.2       
[53] rsconnect_0.8.28  parallel_4.2.0    fastmap_1.1.0     yaml_2.3.6       
[57] clue_0.3-63       colorspace_2.0-3  cluster_2.1.3     memoise_2.0.1    
[61] knitr_1.41        sass_0.4.3
```

Comment: I suspected a conflict of class names but I didn't find one. Could you share a minimal version of your Rmarkdown code?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent This is an interactive document.  There are three shiny chunks embeded in it.  A scss file is called in each shiny chunk.  

<br>The mentioned tabs and javascript are located in RMarkdown, not in shiny chunks.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent 

I created a new rmarkdown file.  I call a css file on the yaml for the html document.  I copied and pasted the mentioned codes and java script.  No Problem.  However, when adding `runtime: shiny`, I encountered this problem.  This is how I identify the root cause.

The rmarkdown file I am working on is an interactive document with three shiny chunks.  The mentioned tabs and javascript are located in RMarkdown, not in shiny chunks.

Comment: If you don't post the code we can only guess, and this is hard.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I edited my question by sharing codes.  I deactivated `runtime: shiny` in yaml,  tabs worked.  However, if it is activated, tabs did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but `id="app_1"` and `id="app_2"` are changed to `id="section-app_1"` and `id="section-app_2"` when one uses `runtime: shiny`. So you have to change your calls to `tablabel` accordingly:

```html
<div class="tab">
<button class="tablinks active" onclick="tablabel(event, 'section-app_1')">Application 1</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="tablabel(event, 'section-app_2')">Application 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The change did not make difference. :(  In fact, it reproduced my problem. The content under tab "Application 1" showed at first.  When clicking tab "Application 2", the content under tab "Application 2" did not show.  When clicking tab "Application 1", the content under this tab disappeared.

Comment: I added my session info above.  Could you please help me to understand why you can but I can't?

Comment: @pinawa Inspect the HTML code, probably the `id` are modified.

Comment: I suspected conflicts from other loaded libraries.  Then I terminated R and closed all projects.  I created a new Rmarkdown file, copied, and pasted all of the content.  I had clean and pure environment.  There were nothing else but the simplest/shortest codes.  I still could not get what worked for you.  Weird!

Comment: I also renamed `id` with words like `london`, `toronto`. Same outcome.

Comment: @pinawa Right-click -> inspect

Answer (score 1):

I tried a different approach, and worked.  Thank you @StéphaneLaurent

```
.nav-pills>li>a{
  background-color: #f1e4ff;
  color:black
}

.nav-pills>li>a:hover{
  background-color: #e4e5ff;
  color:black
} 

.nav-pills>li>a:focus, 
.nav-pills>li.active>a,     
.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, 
.nav-pills>li.active>a:focus{
     background-color: #2b8cc4;
     color: #fff;
     }
```